# ListView AddRange of Items starting from SubItem[1]

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView that already has a populated first column.
I can easily use :

```
MylistView.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item })
```

but since I already have the first column populated, I tried using:

```
MylistView.Items[0].SubItems.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item })
```

but I just get an error:
[image]

I can always use the `string[]` overload, but is there a way to use the `ListViewItem[]` instead for the Subitems?

Here's my code:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
        exp[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString(),
        exp2[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString()
    });
listView2.Items[0].SubItems.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item });
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: incorrect overload, i'll edit my post to put the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why don't you just do:

```
listView2.Items[0].SubItems
         .AddRange(new [] { exp[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString(),
                            exp2[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString(),
                          });
```

The method expects either an array of `strings` or `ListViewSubItems`.